# string comparison on 2 lists

Tags: python, string, list

I have 2 lists.

```
a = ['this;mango', 'is:red', 'test;cat']
b = ['man', 'is', 'can']
```

I want to iterate each element of b and check if that string is present in list a. How can i do that ?

for above example output will be:

```
# is
```

Comment: What separators are you using for the strings in `a`? In the example above you have `;` and `:`.

Comment: separators can be any. i just want to check if string in b is present or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ['this;mango', 'is:red', 'test;cat']
b = ['man', 'is', 'can']

import re

for elem in b:
    for test in a:
        if re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(elem) + r'\b', test):
            print elem
```

Using *List Comprehension:*

```
>>> a = ['this;mango', 'is:red', 'test;cat']
>>> b = ['man', 'is', 'can']
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> [elem for elem in b if any(re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(elem) + r'\b', test) for test in a)]
['is']
```

---

Another version with `map` and `lambda` to avoid the `explicit` loop over `a`:

```
>>> [elem for elem in b if any(map(lambda test: re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(elem) + r'\b', test), a))]
['is']
```

Comment: is it required to use 2 for loops?

Comment: @sam. You have to use 2 for loops, since you have to iterate over both the lists.

Comment: we cant try this in one liner or within one for and list comprehension?

Comment: @AramKocharyan. I think that should work.  re.search will not return any matched value in that case.

Comment: @sam. Added the list comprehension version.

Comment: @RohitJain: thanks man, but my problem is i want to do some operation if elements of b present in a. so i want one for loop for iterating through b but i dont want another for loop and i am not understanding how to do that. your answers are good but my program needs one loop for b.

Comment: Why do you want it using just a single for loop?

Comment: If you really need a single loop, you could use alternation and do a single re.search. Also compile it beforehand.

Comment: @sam Check the last edit. I've added the code that avoids loop over `a` and only loops over `b`. Don't know whether you really want this.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [13]: words = set(reduce(operator.add, (re.split(r'[:;]', s) for s in a)))

In [14]: words
Out[14]: set(['this', 'is', 'cat', 'mango', 'test', 'red'])

In [15]: [w for w in b if w in words]
Out[15]: ['is']
```

Comment: but separators can be any. i only want to see if string is present or not irrespective of seperators

Answer (score 1):

I think you really have to specify your seperators in a, otherwise "man" should also be found.

```
>>> a = ['this;mango', 'is:red', 'test;cat']
>>> b = ['man', 'is', 'can']
>>> [elem for elem in b if elem in " ".join(a)]
['man', 'is']
```

Comment: `''.join(a)` will lead to `'gois'` being found.

Answer (score 1):

Taking @NPE's solution and hoping non-word chars `\W` is OK.

```
In [221]: a = ['this;mango', 'is:red', 'test;cat']

In [222]: right = set(reduce(operator.add, list(re.split(r'[\W]', s) for s in a)))

In [223]: right
Out[223]: set(['this', 'is', 'cat', 'mango', 'test', 'red'])

In [224]: left = set(['man', 'is', 'can'])

In [225]: left
Out[225]: set(['is', 'can', 'man'])

In [226]: left &  right
Out[226]: set(['is'])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
[i for i in b if any(i in re.split(r'\W', j) for j in a)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine b's elements to avoid a second loop :

```
import re

a = ['this;mango', 'is:red', 'test;cat']
b = ['man', 'is', 'can']


def words_in_strings(words, strings):
    pat = re.compile('|'.join(words))
    for i in strings:
        m = pat.search(i)
        if m:
            yield m.group(0)

for i in words_in_strings(b, a):
    print i
```